# Setting axes ranges/limits for time series data (HH:MM:SS)

Tags: r, time, range, series, axes

I'm working with time series data in R. Specifically, I am trying to plot a dependent variable (Download Speed) against a time (between 0:00:00 and 24:59:59) during which the data point was captured.

However, I am having trouble setting limits on the x-axis. I want the axis to start at 00:00:00 and end at 24:59:59. I am using the following function:

```
plot(dt$Time, dt$Download, main = 'Download Speed Over the Course of a Day', xlab = 'Hour', ylab = 'Mb/s')
```

Where dt is a table containing the variables "Time" and "Download". I think I should be using the `xlim` argument but I'm having a tough time with it.

Here is a sample section of the data:

`4/24/2017  22:23:05    33.62   5.65    30.751
4/24/2017   23:23:30    38.88   5.64    42.49`

Thanks

Comment: Please, add a section of your dataset.